# Image moves relative to original location rather than the window

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have an image and I have it start out in a specific location in the middle of the screen.  Various things happen and I want to change the position of this image however the transformation occurs relative to the image's previous location rather than relative to the window.  I get the feeling this isn't something that's wrong with my code rather just some weird feature of WPF that I'm not grasping.

So what method should I be using to move an image relative to the window?

currently I'm trying

```
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, location.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, location.Y);
```

this doesn't work btw.  It moves the image, but the image is moved relative to the images previous location rather than the window.

And here is the code for the image I'm trying to move.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.LetterBlock"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Dictionaries/LetterBlockTypes.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Image Name="LB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{DynamicResource BLB}" Width="50" Height="50" 
       MouseDown="LetterBlock_MouseDown" MouseMove="LetterBlock_MouseMove" MouseUp="LetterBlock_MouseUp" >
</Image>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I think that since your parent canvas isn't declared as taking up the entire screen size, this is to be expected. I guess the canvas is automatically given the dimensions of the user control.

Comment: could you post the full event handler of `LetterBlock_MouseMove` or the concerned one?

Comment: Calling `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` on the UserControl itself doesn't make much sense (unless it is really contained in a Canvas, which of course you can't rely on). Are you perhaps intending to move the Image control relative to the UserControl?

Comment: Weisman you actually had the answer to the problem.  I had a canvas within a canvas and apparently that was the problem.  This smaller which had the letterblocks added as children was what was screwing everything up.  For everyone else.  Yes I put all of my graphics inside of a canvas.  Is there another way I'm supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're moving image? Try:

```
    Canvas.SetLeft(yourImage, location.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(yourImage, location.Y);
```

Considering you're handling the Image LetterBlock_MouseDown, in your UserControl, I don't see how you can expect instance of image to be actually "`this`".

Comment: tried that, it doesn't move the image at all.  I only got the image to move with the "this" indicator.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Which one is canvas? Does LetterBlock user control inherit from canvas? Is the LetterBlock user control stretched across window or does it have the same size as Image? Dowload Snoop, add more details to post.

Comment: This won't work, as the Image control is not contained in a Canvas (which is obvious from the question).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct this will solve your issue

```
    Point location = e.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
    Canvas.SetLeft(this, location.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(this, location.Y);
```

in the mouse move event you may be trying to retrieve the mouse location based on the user control or the image. but you should be retrieving for the main window instead as you want the position relative to window.

sample below will hep you retrieve the mouse location relative to the main window. if there is other window you may need to pass the reference accordingly.

```
    e.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

Comment: Ill try that when I get to my programming computer.  Sounds promising.